# Custom string class equality

Tags: c#, string, unit-testing, compare, equals

I'm making a custom string class. (mainly for self-edification purposes - I know I'm not going to come up with anything better than the regular `string` class that I couldn't do just as easily with extension methods.)  I'm running into a weird problem with testing for equality in my unit tests.  It works in almost every respect except one.  Here's the unit tests:

```
MyString myStr = "MyNewString";
Assert.AreEqual("MyNewString", myStr); //Fails
Assert.AreEqual(myStr, "MyNewString");
Assert.IsTrue(myStr.Equals("MyNewString"));
Assert.IsTrue(("MyNewString").Equals(myStr));
Assert.IsTrue(myStr == "MyNewString");
Assert.IsTrue("MyNewString" == myStr);

string realString = "MyNewString";
Assert.AreEqual(realString, myStr); //Fails
Assert.AreEqual(myStr, realString);
Assert.IsTrue(myStr.Equals(realString));
Assert.IsTrue(realString.Equals(myStr));
Assert.IsTrue(myStr == realString);
Assert.IsTrue(realString == myStr);
```

In both the cases where it fails, it will succeed if I add a `.ToString()` after `myStr`, but this is not required in any of the other cases.  I'm guessing it's because `string`'s `Equals` methods don't know about my class, even though I've got implicit conversions set up.  The relevant parts of the class are as follows:

```
public struct MyString : ICloneable, IComparable<MyString>, IComparable<string>,
    IEnumerable<char>, IEquatable<MyString>, IEquatable<string>
{
    private char[] text;

    //Constructors
    ...

    public static implicit operator MyString(string s)
    {
        return s == null ? null : new MyString(s);
    }
    public static implicit operator string(MyString s) { return s.ToString(); }

    public static bool operator ==(MyString a, MyString b) { return a.Equals(b); }
    public static bool operator !=(MyString a, MyString b) { return !(a.Equals(b)); }
    public static bool operator ==(MyString a, string b) { return a.Equals(b); }
    public static bool operator !=(MyString a, string b) { return !(a.Equals(b)); }
    public static bool operator ==(string a, MyString b) { return b.Equals(a); }
    public static bool operator !=(string a, MyString b) { return !(b.Equals(a)); }

    public override string ToString() { return new string(text); }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (base.Equals(obj))
            return true;
        if (obj is MyString)
            return this.Equals((MyString)obj);
        if (obj is string)
            return this.Equals((string)obj);
        return false;
    }
    public bool Equals(MyString other) { return this.CompareTo(other) == 0; }
    public bool Equals(string other) { return this.CompareTo(other) == 0; }
}
```

There's `CompareTo()`'s also for both `MyString` and regular `string`, but just trust me that they work.  Is there anything else I can do to make this equality test work?  It seems to work in every other case but this one.  I'm not sure how `Assert.AreEqual` actually operates internally, but if every other method for testing equality works, why does this one fail?

**Edit:** Adding my GetHashCode() as it might be relevant:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    int hash = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++ )
        hash ^= (i * this[i]);
     return hash;
}
```

For sure this probably doesn't match `string.GetHashCode()`, but I have no way of knowing because I can't see their code.  (I can see metadata, but it only includes the headers and not the implementation.)  Tried replacing it with just a shortcut to `string.GetHashCode()`:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return new string(text).GetHashCode();
}
```

Still doesn't work.  Also tried adding an extension method:

```
public static bool Equals(this string a, MyString b) { return b.Equals(a); }
```

That didn't work either.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I'm so very very very curious as to why you're doing this..

Comment: One word.  Practice.  Best way to get really comfortable with a language is to just always be coding something.  Figure out how you'd have to do things if all the fancy classes didn't exist already.  I'm not intending to use this in any production code.  It's merely for my own self-improvement.

Comment: Fair enough.. just thought I'd ask :)

Answer (score 0):

The call stack mentions the call of `Assert.AreEqual(object, object)` 
I assume that this will call `object.Equals(object, object)` that does not call any of your operators. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/29/when-should-i-use-and-when-should-i-use-equals.aspx 
BTW: Please be sure to overwrite `GetHashCode()`

I had to extend it a little bit.
 `Assert.AreEqual(a,b)` calls `object.Equals(a,b)` which calls `a.equals(b)`. So your test calls `string.Equals(b)`.  
The implementation of `string.Equals` does an implicit cast to String for ReferenceEqualsComparism. So, as long as no implicit cast to string exists, the string.equality() will fail.
 In short: Your implicit cast from MyString to string does not work => see [In c# 3.0, is it possible to add implicit operators to the string class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792048/in-c-sharp-3-0-is-it-possible-to-add-implicit-operators-to-the-string-class)

```
  var myStr = "hello" as MyString;   // does call implicit cast to MyString
  var y = myStr as string;           // does not call implicit cast to String becaus you are not owner of string
```

Comment: I did overwrite GetHashCode().  I left it out for simplicity.  Now I know the odds of my hash function matching `string`'s hash function are pretty slim.  Would matching `string`'s hash be the only way to get this particular equality comparison to work?  (Interesting that it works fine when you reverse the operands.)

Comment: Well, I just replaced my GetHashCode() with `return new String(text).GetHashCode();` (easier than trying to guess what `string`'s actual hash function is), and it still fails on those two cases, so that's not it.

Comment: So is the end result that this just can't be done at all?  I can't alter `Assert.AreEqual`, `object.Equals` or `string.Equals` at all.  I can't even extend and override on the string class because it's `sealed`.  (Sealed classes are kind of a jerky thing to do IMO.)  And even extension methods are ignored in this case, so does that mean I'm just out of luck?  Also how does `Assert.IsTrue(realString.Equals(myStr));` work if that's the case?  Wouldn't that also just call `string.Equals`?

Comment: Your comment contains very good points. It`s interesting to see:<br/>`String y = myStr;` works while `String z = myStr as string;` does not compile. So, your example calls the implicit operator by direct assignment during the parameter call while the as-operator fails.<br/> I see no further possibility to get your code run because '=' and 'as' cannot be overloaded.